# WordPress Gutenberg block Inspector Controls: do I need to add a stylesheet for the controls?

Tags: wordpress, padding, margin, styling, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm working on a Gutenberg block for WordPress. I've started adding inspector controls. However I am noticing that the InspectorControls area has no margin or padding, the controls are lined right up with the edge of the sidebar. Am I supposed to include my own stylesheet to fix this? Or am I missing a needed WP admin stylesheet?
[image: Gutenberg Block]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. Wrapping the elements in a **PanelRow** for each element and all of the **PanelRow**s in a **PanelBody** took care of the margin and the padding.
[image: Gutenberg InspectorControls]